# Why this post is Recommend Deletion

Tags: discussion

not sure why [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/6714725) is **Recommend Deletion** can you explain to me please the post has been viewed more than 1180 times

Comment: because it is a question not an answer?

Comment: Views are not an indicator of quality, they're an indicator of popularity.

Comment: Also, it was reasked as a question here:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4376809/how-to-declare-global-array-of-size-defined-in-another-file-in-c99

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It's a question that was posted as an answer.  It's not an answer to the question that was asked. The number of views has nothing to do with the quality or acceptability of a post.